# hacer que un select de dos valores distintos

Tags: javascript

Buena tarde tengo este código pero me gustaría que al elegir una cantidad del select (n6) tenga una cantidad distinta en este caso la cantidad que aparece en el value del select. de antemano gracias por su valioso apoyo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Gloria Perfumes®, perfumes y esencias">
  <meta name="author" content="Grupo Gloria">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

</head><!--/head-->
<script>
function calcular() {
  var n1 = parseInt(document.dosificacion.capacidad.value);

  // alerta
  if (isNaN(n1)) {
    alert('Ingresa la capacidad');
    return;
        }


  var n5 = parseInt(document.dosificacion.dosificacion.value);
  var esencia = (n1 * n5/100).toFixed();
  var n2 = parseInt(esencia);
  var n6 =("0.08");
  var fijador = (n1*n6).toFixed();
  var perfumol = (n1 - n2 - fijador).toFixed();


  document.dosificacion.esencia.value = esencia + " g.";
  document.dosificacion.fijador.value = fijador + " g.";
  document.dosificacion.perfumol.value = perfumol + " g.";


}
</script>
<body>
            <section class="calculator">
                <div class="container">
                                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">

        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container-calculator">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                  </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-right">
                                <div class="panel amounts hoverable">
                                    <p>Ingresa la Capacidad</p>

                            </span>
                              <form name="dosificacion">
                                    <input class="capacidad" name="capacidad" id="amount" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="0"  maxlength="4">

                                    <div class="blink activated"></div>


                                    <p>Concentración</p>

                                        <div>
                                          <select class="concentracion"  name="dosificacion">

                                                <option value=".08">50</option>
                                                <option value=".07">45</option>
                                                <option value=".04">40</option>
                                                <option value=".04">38</option>
                                                <option value=".03">33</option>
                                                <option value=".02">25</option>

                                                </select>
                                              </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-left">
                                <div class="panel cobros hoverable">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                                            <p>Esencia</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <input type="text" class="esencia" name="esencia"id="amount2"></b></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                                            <p>Fijador</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                        <input class="fijador" type="text" name="fijador"id="amount2"><br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                                            <p>Perfumol</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                        <input class="perfumol" type="text" name="perfumol"id="amount2"><br>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                 <div><input class="boton1" type="button" value="dosificacion" onclick="calcular()"></div>

                            </div>


                </div>

                </form>
                <div class="triangle-calculator">

                </div>
            </section>




</body></html>
```

Comment: ¿por qué la etiqueta java? yo solo veo código JavaScript

Comment: perdon soy nuevo por a qui

Comment: no tre apures solo consideralo para la próxima de todos modos ya la quité saludos

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, quieres que al selecciona un valor del select la función calcular pueda obtener ese valor?

Comment: el <select class="concentracion"  name="dosificacion"> es esencial para el calculo de toda la tabla pero elige los valores 50, 45 , 40 , 38 ,33 y 25, lo que quisiera es que al elejir por ejemplo el valor 50    var n6 =("0.08");  tome el valor value=".08" si elijo el valor 45 tome el valor   value=".07"  pero solo quiero que (n6) recoja este valor